# Unable to access vsftpd from public ip

Tags: vsftpd

I am trying to setup a vsftpd on ubuntu

I have installed successfully installed vsftpd

My networks works like this

Lan network on host(localhost,127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.105) -> connects to router(192.168.1.1(LAN) -> 10.255.1.204(WAN)) -> connects to ISP (10.255.1.1 -> DNS -> 106.34.26.78(public ip)). (Note: The ip addresses used is just to illustrate and not real ones)

I have enabled port forwarding on my router, which redirects all requests to port 21 to my local machine on which vsftp deamon is running.

I am able to access ftp from my internal LAN addresses and the interface that connects to ISP (i.e., 10.255.1.204). But I am unable to access it from my public ip address(i.e., 106.34.26.78), I get the following message:

```
Status: Connecting to 106.34.26.78:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

My vsftpd.conf (/etc/vsftpd.conf)

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES

#virutal user settings
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
nopriv_user=vsftpd
guest_username=vsftpd
```

My vsftpd (/etc/pam.d/vsftpd)

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

I am breaking my head over this since a month now, I found few articles, But they were not related to access using public IP.

**EDIT**

I have also enabled port forwarding on port 20.

Comment: first give the output of telnet with 20,21 port from outside also

Answer (score 1):

From your networking setup your problem might be that of [hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat)

Additionally you seem to try and negotiate a TLS connection with the [`AUTTH TLS`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4217#section-12.1) command but you have don't any references to enable TLS support in your `vsftpd.conf`

Although for a different FTP server also read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/774113/37681) on the potential issues with FTP over TLS and NAT.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this by enabling ssl and commenting few lines in my vsftpd.conf for allowing system users instead of the ones defined using pam.d.

I can now access sftp (and I have a strong doubt that my ISP is blocking access on 21, Any how it gave me more secure access), From outside network with the following /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES

#virutal user settings
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
#guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
#pam_service_name=vsftpd
#nopriv_user=vsftpd
#guest_username=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO

require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH

start on (filesystem
        and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
```

Hope, it helps any one who encounter the same in future.